# Odd syntax for ssh and bash to run command

Tags: ssh, bash, shell, shell-script

I'm pretty new to shell/bash scripting and I'm writing a script on OSX to automate some rather tedious efforts. I'm trying to run a portion of my script on a remote host using `ssh`. There's a common script on both machines, which I'll call `ascript`. On both machines, this script is in /usr/local/bin.

I know that I need the full path to `ascript` on my remote host to run it like so:

`ssh user@otherHost bash -c "/usr/local/bin/ascript --FlagToDoSomething"`

However, I've found that `--FlagToDoSomething` only runs correctly if I write it the following way in my script:

`ssh user@otherHost bash -c "
/usr/local/bin/ascript --FlagToDoSomething"`

(ie it needs a new line after the open quotes) I get a message in the Terminal window saying `bash: -c: option requires an argument`, but the rest of it continues to run and I get the output that I'm expecting. If I don't do that, I just get the output as though I just typed in `ascript` and hit enter (so the usage info).

If I remove `bash -c` it works correctly, but I'm only doing it this way because, for whatever reason:
`ssh user@otherHost "output=$(/usr/local/bin/ascript --FlagToDoSomething; echo \$output)"` 
attempts to run this function on the local host, which causes some funky output. And I need to run multiple commands on the remote host before terminating my ssh connection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ssh user@otherHost "output=$(/usr/local/bin/ascript --FlagToDoSomething; echo \$output)"
```

What the heck is that supposed to do?  `$output` isn't set yet, since the echo is inside the `$(command substitution)`.

Also, `$()` is expanded by the shell inside double quotes.  That's why it runs locally.  Use single quotes to avoid it.

Perhaps you want

```
output=$(ssh u@oh '/usr/local/bin/ascript --FlagToDoSomething')
```

Comment: What the heck it's supposed to do is exactly what I'm getting with single quotes! Duh, that was stupid of me. Essentially, I wanted the output of "--FlagToDoSomething" to be echo'd. Using double quotes wasn't doing that for me, so I tried to figure out some way of using echo to do that. Clearly, that compounded issues that I didn't intend for. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, well the ")" is just in the wrong spot actually. Should be right after  `--FlagToDoSomething`. Regardless, using single quotes seems like a less verbose (and potentially screwy) way of accomplishing that.

Comment: @bocks: The `)` in the wrong spot was my point.  The echo was inside the command substitution!  Note that using `echo $output` instead of `echo "$output"` collapses all whitespace (including newlines) in the output of `ascript` into single spaces.  Is that what you're trying to do?  Otherwise you don't need the capture/echo at all.  If it is what you want, `echo $(command)` should do the same thing.

Comment: Ah, all of this stuff is super useful Peter. Thanks! And yup, will be accepting now. Just wanted to make sure it worked correctly on my end before making this answer green.

Comment: @bocks: cool.  I wouldn't normally bug people so quickly about accepting, just that I wanted the 200-daily-rep badge, and it's only 1hr to the end of the day (UTC).  Had two oddly-high-scoring answers racking up rep for me today. :P

Answer (score 0):

Remove "-c" and put the whole shebang in quotes:

```
output=$(ssh widrick@widrick.net "bash /usr/local/bin/ascript --testable=fly"); 

echo $output;
```

Comment: Am I supposed to leave the `bash` in quotes?

Comment: you're welcome to play with the quotes... but it works for me exactly as written ```ARGES GIVEN: --testable=fly```